# Ignore "Cannot resolve symbol" in Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper

Say I have a method signature like this:

```
protected override void Initialize(params object[] parameters)
```

... and the object can accurately handle all the parameters.  When I do the validation of these parameters (say setting them to fields of the class) and one is `null`, I'd like to be able to do something like this without a warning from ReSharper:

```
if (parameters[5] == null)
    /* Yields:  Cannot resolve symbol 'knownParameterName' */
    throw new ArgumentNullException("knownParameterName");
```

In the context of my app, this warning is ok.  Does anyone know what rule I need to ignore?

Comment: As of R# 6 (or 6.1?) this can be done with the comment: `// ReSharper disable NotResolvedInText` (or setting the inspection options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting the parameter names into a static readonly string array and calling

```
throw new ArgumentNullException(initializationParameterNames[5]);
```

?

You could do it like this:

```
protected override void Initialize(params object[] parameters) 
{
    for (int paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < initializationParameterNames.Length; paramIndex++)
    {
        if (parameters.Length <= paramIndex)
            throw new ArgumentException("Missing " + initializationParamterNames[paramIndex]);
        if (parameters[paramIndex] == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(initializationParameterNames[paramIndex]);
    }
    ...
}
```